# jQuery Higlight items that are more than one in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlighting

I am trying to highlight items that are more than one in a list with different colours with jQuery. Is below achievable easily?

For example. Take the ul below

```
<ul id="inul">
    <li id="s0" class="list">
        <span id="ip0">127.0.0.1</span>
        <span id="ua0">SonyEricssonK800iv/R1KG Browser/NetFront/3.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1</span>
    </li>
    <li id="s1" class="list">
        <span id="ip1">127.0.0.1</span>
        <span id="ua1">Nokia3120classic/2.0 (09.41) Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 nokia3120classic/UC Browser7.6.1.82/69/352 UNTRUSTED/1.0</span>
    </li>
    <li id="s2" class="list">
        <span id="ip2">127.0.0.1</span>
        <span id="ua2">SonyEricssonW580i/R8BE Browser/NetFront/3.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1</span>
    </li>
    <li id="s3" class="list">
        <span id="ip3">127.0.0.1</span>
        <span id="ua3">SonyEricssonK800iv/R1KG Browser/NetFront/3.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1</span>
    </li>
    <li id="s4" class="list">
        <span id="ip4">127.0.0.1</span>
        <span id="ua4">Nokia3120classic/2.0 (09.41) Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 nokia3120classic/UC Browser7.6.1.82/69/352 UNTRUSTED/1.0</span>
    </li>
    <li id="s5" class="list">
        <span id="ip5">127.0.0.2</span>
        <span id="ua5">SonyEricssonW580i/R8BE Browser/NetFront/3.3 Profile/MIDP-2.0      Configuration/CLDC-1.1</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are two of each browser user agent and 4 of same ip (127.0.0.1) and 1 127.0.0.2.

What i am hoping to achieve is that identical spans would be colored with same color while assigning different color to each identical set.

Just to be clear, end result should look like image below

[image]

**UPDATE** With the help of WSkid I ahve manged to achive what i want. See update http://pastebin.ca/2058058 or working version at http://jsfiddle.net/mUGVR/15/

Answer (score 1):

The following is terribly in efficient and hacky, but it might start you down the right road of storing a hash-like map and keeping a count to add your needed styles:

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mUGVR/.

```
var ipList={};
var ipCount=0;
var userList={};
var userCount=0;

$('li.list').each(function(i){
   var spans = $(this).children();
    spans[0] = $(spans[0]);
    spans[1] = $(spans[1]);

    if(ipList[spans[0].text()]!=null)
    {
        spans[0].addClass('ip'+ipList[spans[0].text()]);
    }
    else 
    {
        ipList[spans[0].text()] = ipCount;
        spans[0].addClass('ip'+ipCount);
        ipCount++;
    }

    if(userList[spans[1].text()]!=null)
    {
        spans[1].addClass('user'+userList[spans[1].text()]);
    }
    else 
    {
        userList[spans[1].text()] = userCount;
        spans[1].addClass('user'+userCount);
        userCount++;
    }
});
```

With css:

```
.ip0 {background:yellow;}
.user0{background:cyan;}
.user1{background:green;}
.user2{background:red;}
```

Comment: Sigh, always a minute or two behind. Gary's answer is almost the exact same, this is just adding classes instead of direct css styles.

Comment: Nice, didn't even cross my mind to use classes in this, due to how many styles/colours there could be.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind me being pick and PIA :) 

Your code starts highlighting even if there aren't more than one of an ip or user agent. Try changing first ip to unique one on your fiddle to see what i mean. Unique ip gets highlighted.

Is it possible to make it so if and ip or user agent wasn't listed more than once it would not get changed?

Comment: after working on your example I have managed to achive what i want for Ip list.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mUGVR/12/

Comment: Very nice! I wanted to avoid duplicate $.each() calls, I'm sure there is a way but yours works and runs fairly quickly (duplicated to 100 or so ip's and it ran in 1.8 seconds on ie7).

Answer (score 0):

Like this? **Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8A5dY/1

```
// highlights ips
$('li span:first-child').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text() == '127.0.0.1');
}).css('background', 'yellow');

var colorMap = [];
var currentColor = 0;

$('li span:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var color = colorMap[text] ||
                ['lightblue', 'red', 'blue', 'green'][currentColor++];

    colorMap[text] = color;

    $(this).css('background', color);
});
```

Comment: like this, but, ip or user agents aren't static. list it could have different ips and user agents

Comment: What do you mean? You said there is 2 different IPs. For the user agents, just keep expanding your color array or get a colour hex code increaser so each color remains unique.

Comment: return ($(this).text() == '127.0.0.1');

127.0.0.1 is just a sample, data loaded from a database of ips and user agents

Comment: And you want them to be highlighted in the same manner? Why not just use the .each function for the ips too. As a side note this site is for helping with code, can you demonstrate you are attempting to change the code to suit what you need. It's not the kind of site where we spoon feed everything ;)

Comment: I know and you are right. I don't usually ask unless i am really desperate and grateful with the help.

Comment: Can you update your screenshot to show what you really want, including and describing all possible datasets.

Comment: lets remove user agent and think about the ip.
an ul with random ips. 
im loping in the ul and looking for ips listed more than once. 

if thats the case assign a highlight color to that particular ip and move forward.

if an  ip is listed only one time i don't do anything.